# Why can I not use fscanf() to read consecutive characters from a file?

Tags: c, file, scanf

I am trying to write a program to count the number of lines in a file by using the following code..

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
if(argc!=2)
{
  printf("invalid no. of arguments\nUsage:lc <FILENAME>\n");
  return 1;
}


FILE *in=fopen(argv[1],"r");

char c;
int count=0;
fscanf(in,"%c",&c); //take the first character

while(c!=EOF)
{
  if(c=='\n')
   count++;
   fscanf(in,"%c",&c);
}
fclose(in);

printf("TOTAL LINES:%d\n",count);
return 0;
}
```

I am aware that this can be achieved by using fgetc(), but I am curious to know why fscanf() doesn't work here.

all help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your indentation is wrong and confusing. And [fscanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) returns an item count that you forgot to test. At last, on Linux notably, `stdin` is *line* buffered. Read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `EOF` is not a `char` it is an `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to test the result count of [fscanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). In particular, your program is completely wrong when the processed file is an empty one.

```
while(c!=EOF)
```

That can *never* happen (after any `fscanf(in,"%c",&c)`...). `EOF` is *not* a valid character (so by definition is outside of all the possible values of a `char`). For instance, on *your* system, `char` could be unsigned 8 bits, and `EOF` could be -1 (`EOF` is documented -in [§7.21.1 of the C11 standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.1)- to be some negative `int`, not some `char`). So the type of `EOF` is not `char`. And on my Linux/Debian/x86-64 that is happening.

Read much more carefully the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io) related to `<stdio.h>`

In general, read the documentation of *every* function that you are using. And learn [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

> this can be achieved by using fgetc()

Yes, and in your case you'll better use [fgetc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc). Again, read its documentation. It is very likely that `fgetc` is much faster (since more low-level) than `fscanf`. Most *implementations* of `fscanf` are using `fgetc` (or its equivalent).

At last, some [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) *implementations* are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software). On Linux, both GNU [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) and [musl-libc](https://www.musl-libc.org/) are. You could study their source code. You'll learn a lot by doing so. Both are built above Linux [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html).

Comment: Even worse, is not outside of all the possible values of `char`. Just `unsigned char`

Comment: No, it is not specified in the standard if `char` is `signed` or  `unsigned` (both does happen). But `EOF` is not a valid `char`; on implementations with signed 8 bits `char`, `EOF` cannot be -1 (which would then be a *valid* `char`) but could be +128 (which is then not a valid `char`)

Comment: Yes, and I'm not disagreeing with anything here, but it does seems like there is a little gray area if I am reading [6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers(p2)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1p2) correctly. It seems that section would explicitly allow `char c; ... while (c != EOF) ...` because the `"integer conversion rank"` [of `char`] `"is less than or equal to the rank of int and unsigned int."` I don't recommend it, but that is the counter argument I see.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch "it is not outside of all the possible values for `char`" does not contradict "standard does not specify the range of char". But `EOF` is negative so it cannot be +128.

Comment: Are you sure that the C standard specifies that EOF should be negative? (even if in practice it is). Certainly `fscanf(in,"%c",&c)` will never set `c` to `EOF`. When that `fscanf` fails, `c` remains unchanged!

Comment: "`EOF`

which expands to an integer constant expression, with type int and a negative value, that is returned by several functions to indicate end-of-file, that is, no more input from a stream;"

Comment: Remember that `EOF` *is* the return value from failed `fscanf` too... would not make sense for it to be +128 :D

Comment: Thanks. I forgot that clause. So `EOF` would be -129 on systems with 8 bit signed `char`-s

Comment: Right...you guys were of great help and thanks for guiding me!